# Get xml of excel workbook using office.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, office365, office-js, office-addins

How to read the webextension xml part form an excel file using my office add-in. Is it possible with office.js? I was trying with [`getFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=word-js-preview#getfileasync-filetype--options--callback-), but it is not giving the xml. I am using [Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin) to embed script lab Add-in, which generates the following webextension xml. Is it possible to read the value of `SnippetToImport` property with office.js

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<we:webextension xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11" id="{635BF0CD-42CC-4174-B8D2-6D375C9A759E}">
  <we:reference id="wa104380862" version="1.1.0.0" store="en-US" storeType="OMEX" />
  <we:alternateReferences />
  <we:properties>
   <we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true" />
   <we:property name="SnippetToImport" value="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;gist&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1234&quot;}" />
  </we:properties>
  <we:bindings />
  <we:snapshot xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" />
</we:webextension>
```

Comment: Could you please help clarify a bit more on xml part of an excel file? do you mean custom XML part?